# Using CSS to scale a child to fit within a parent

Tags: html, css, layout

Is it possible to ***scale*** a child (of known size) to match the width of it's parent (of unknown width)?

The child's size will be wider that it's parent. I need to find a way to scale it down so that it displays the entire child within the bounds of the parent.

[image: before and after]

I am hoping to avoid using javascript if possible.

Here is the code:

```css
.a-very-wide-child {
  /* the exact size of the child is known */
  width: 3000px;
  height: 500px;

  /* I am trying to scale this element to match the width of its parent. */
  /* I am thinking probably what I need is a value for [HERE]. I am open 
     to other suggestions though. */
  transform: scale(calc(/*  [HERE] */));
  transform-origin: top left;

/* I am NOT wanting to use width rules to resize the child. */
/* no: width: 100%; */
/* no: max-width: 100%; */
}


.a-small-parent {
  /* has no style rules of note */
  /* the width of the parent is not known */
  /* the height of the parent is not known exactly, but known to be tall 
     enough to not be of concern */
}


/* Below is just styling and is safe to ignore. */

.a-small-parent {
  border: 5px solid teal;
}

.a-very-wide-child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #888, transparent);
  border: 5px solid gold;
}

.container{
  width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=a-small-parent>
    <pre class=a-very-wide-child>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/500" alt="">
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use %? And is the use of JS not an option?

Comment: @Geshode Using width % changes the layout of the children as you can see: https://i.imgur.com/KjYpeqG.png. I need the "After" result shown above which is quite different. JS is not entirely off the table but would be more burdensome implement in the application it is being put to use in and I would like to see if it can be done in CSS alone first.

Comment: why dont you try width:100% inside the parent. Also scale isn't quite used for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off late, I have been fiddling with all kinds of element size and font scaling for responsive behavior and knew I had already created something to solve your issue (see Codepen links at the end).

To start with the downside: you cannot avoid using at least some Javascript as you will need a *unitless scale factor* for the CSS `transform: scale(..)` to function properly. And for responsiveness purposes, you will need to know the *current `clientWidth`* of the parent container. This is also true for *container queries* and their respective units. *With CSS you just cannot strip units off a property value*.

**Equation for the scale factor:** `parent.clientWidth / child.Width` (unitless).

When scaling down with `transform: scale(..)`, HTML will continue to use the original space the element occupied in the document causing a (huge) space surrounding the element. Fiddling with `transform-origin` will not solve that issue, but with negative `margin`s we can 'remove' the excess space and snuggly fit our element in its parent. The demo assumes default `transform-origin: center`, simply meaning that below equation is true for all four margin properties.

**Equation for margin space offset:** `offset = -1px * (childSize - scaled childSize) / 2` (with 'px'-unit conversion). Because of the current issue we can suffice to address *width* values only, so `childSize` reads `childWidth`.

The snippet uses *CSS custom variables* in all equations for easy manipulation and testing. The code is heavily commented, so I expect little surprises there. Let me know if I need to elaborate on something.

**Be aware** that when *slowly* resizing the browser you will sometimes see blank, single pixel lines above/aside the scaled element. This is not the result of the above equation, but due to rounding issues I have not taken into account. With division in equations you will get decimal values eventually causing partial pixels. Rule of thumb: *part of a pixel is a full pixel*. This would require additional Javascript as CSS does not `round(..)`, `ceil(..)` or `floor(..)`.

Some Codepens with variations on scaling I have created:

- a web page with a list of scaled down `<iframe>` elements made to look like cards [Codepen: Runtime scaling cards, CSS only](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/ExpXeVd)
- and [Codepen: SO75129247 (WIP)](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/GRBvyZR) of a SO question I haven't gotten around to answer, incorporating the above Codepen as a nested `<iframe>`.

**The snippet**

```js
// Assign event listeners to show scaling works on resize
window.addEventListener('load'  , setVariables); // Initial run
window.addEventListener('resize', setVariables); // Reponsiveness scaling

// parent elements involved
const parents = document.querySelectorAll('.a-small-parent');

function setVariables() {
    // Modify CSS custom variables to hold current element
    // width/height per parent
    parents.forEach((el) => {
        el.style.setProperty('--parentClientWidth' , el.clientWidth);
        el.style.setProperty('--parentClientHeight', el.clientHeight);
    });
};
```

```css
.a-small-parent {
    /* has no style rules of note. CHECK! */
    /* the width of the parent is not known. CHECK! */
    /* the height of the parent is not known exactly, but known to be tall 
       enough to not be of concern. CHECK! */

    /* [OPTIONAL] defined here, just for clarity */
    --parentClientWidth : 0; /* Modified by JS */
    --parentClientHeight: 0;
}

.a-very-wide-child {
    /* the exact size of the child is known. CHECK! */
    
    /* Define the size of the child element, unitless  */
    --childWidth : 3000; /* We need unitless values to */
    --childHeight:  500; /* calculate scale and offset */

    width : calc(var(--childWidth)  * 1px); /* Could be hardcoded units */
    height: calc(var(--childHeight) * 1px); /* like the original code   */

    /* Define the parent to child scale factors for the transform, unitless */
    --scaleH: calc(var(--parentClientWidth) / var(--childWidth)); /* Horizontal */
    /*
        When in the below 'transform' functions scaleX(..) and scaleY(..)
        are being used, two transform-scale variables must be declared and
        used for scaling and margin offset calculation.
    */
    --scaleV: var(--scaleH); /* For now, Horizontal/Vertical scales are equal */

    /* I am trying to scale this element to match the width of its parent. */
    /* I am thinking probably what I need is a value for [HERE]. I am open 
       to other suggestions though. CHECK! */

    /* Scale the child element relative to current parent clientWidth and clientHeight */
    transform: scale(var(--scaleH), var(--scaleV));

    /* I am NOT wanting to use width rules to resize the child. CHECK! */
    /* no: width: 100%; */
    /* no: max-width: 100%; */

    /*
        'transform: scale(..)' scales an element but leaves the original space the element
        occupied intact. Essentially, leaving a big open space after scale down, or a burst out
        of the parent when scaling up.
    
        Assuming the element is scaled down and uses default 'transform-origin: center'
        we need to calculate margin offsets to correct the gaps:

        T/B: offset = -1 * (childHeight - scaled childHeight) / 2
        R/L: offset = -1 * (childWidth  - scaled childWidth)  / 2

        - childHeight/childWidth offset as their values differ
        - multiplied by -1 as we need a negative offset to shrink the gap
        - divided    by 2  as we must shrink either side (Top and Bottom, Right and Left)

        The sign of below 'offset-unit-multiplier' depends on the current scale factor
        - negative when scale factor < 1
        - positive when scale factor > 1

        This requires additional Javascript to determine (not implemented).
    */

    /* Assumed to be 'negative' in this demo: always scaling down */
    --offset-unit-multiplier: -1px;
    
    --offsetTB: calc(var(--offset-unit-multiplier) * (var(--childHeight) - var(--scaleV) * var(--childHeight)) / 2);
    --offsetRL: calc(var(--offset-unit-multiplier) * (var(--childWidth)  - var(--scaleH) * var(--childWidth))  / 2);

    margin: var(--offsetTB) var(--offsetRL);

    /*
       Moved down as it is not needed. However, when assigned here,
       the calculations for the margin offset must be changed accordingly.
       This would require some testing/fiddling to find out what works best.
    */    
    /*  transform-origin: top left;/* Obsolete */
}

/* Below is just DEMO styling and is safe to ignore. */
* { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 1px dashed; /* for debugging */
}
pre { margin: 0 }
img { height: 100%; object-fit: cover }

.a-small-parent    { border: 5px solid teal }
.a-very-wide-child { border: 5px solid red; background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #888, transparent) }
.container         { width : 40vw }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class=a-small-parent>
        <pre class=a-very-wide-child>
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/500" alt="">
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post this. To be honest I ended up going a different direction and no longer need to resolve this particular issue and I neglected to update my question. None the less thank you for your help.